# HttpClient Post request with Json body

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to send a `POST` request to a API with a JSON body and a param (`param`) in the URL.

The request goes through fine but the response sent back from API suggests that the values from `customObj` are not passed through to the API?

I have changed my implementation several times but can't seem to figure out as to why the body message couldn't be getting passed? I have checked the `curl` and can see it consists the body and JSON message.

Only thing I can think of is `Content-Type:` has `application/json-patch+json` whereas it should be only `application/json`

```
class customObj{
    public string param1 {get;set;}
    public string param2 {get;set;}
    public string param3 {get;set;}
}
```

```
string result;
var url = $"/test/{param}/dothis";

var jSonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customObj);

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.testapi.com");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    using (var response =
        await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(jSonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")))
    {
        using (var content = response.Content)
        {
            var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

CURL

```
curl -X POST "<url>" -H "accept: application/json" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d "{ \"param1\": \"test1\", \"param2\": \"test2\", \"param3\": \"test3\"}"
```

Comment: I have code in production that mimics what you're doing.  The only real difference I see is how I'm specifying the headers. I'm using the following:
                
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: @MyItchyChin tried with your suggestion to no avail. I can't see as to why it could be stopping the params to be passed through? or even from the other api from reading it?

Comment: Do you have the code for the API you're hitting or is it third-party? Also, just to confirm, the curl version works?

Comment: Just my thinking. The issue is likely on the other end.

Comment: I am actually doing a conversion from `Java` into `Asp.Net` `Core` and Java version works fine :( going to look at it again to make sure I haven't missed anything.

Comment: Is the api developed by .net core? If so, share us the defination for the action. What is the current result for `var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();`? Does the api receive the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved this. The issue was due to me using `PascalCasing` inside my `Json` body and the end point using `camelCasing` so it was not able to read the property values.

So instead of this

```
var jSonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customObj);
```

I had to use the camel casing resolver when I serilized my json object.

```
var changePassObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customObj, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings 
                { 
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
                });
```